# JSTL Core <c:if> not working

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm passing a parameter `page` to my JSP page, now I have made an if statement on there, but it doesn't work.

```
<c:if var="${param.page == "course"}">class="active"</c:if>
```

Does somebody know what my problem is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to use it would be:

```
<c:if test="${param eq 'greetTheWorld'}">
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</c:if>
```

Consider it just like an `if` clause on programming.

```
if (1 < 0) {
  print("something is wrong!");
}
```

Comment: Correct, except that you can't put double quotes inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use eq to check equality.

```
<c:if var="${param.page eq 'course'}">class="active"</c:if>
```